# php не видит существующие файлы

Tags: php, require

код:

```
require "../../app/actions/db.php";
```

директория файла:

```
app/actions/db.php
```

Ошибка:

```
require(../../app/actions/db.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in [путь к файлу]
```

Comment: Вы уверены, что форматирование не съело ваш код?

Comment: @ШвеевАлексей нет

Comment: Какой путь файла с кодом?

Comment: /help/remarks/index.php

Comment: `require __DIR__ . '/../../app/actions/db.php'`

Answer (score 0):

```
require $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/app/actions/db.php";
```